# Populating PDF form fields and keeping the PDF file editable

Tags: vb.net, pdf, pdf-generation, itext

I have a PDF file which contains a series of blank form fields. In code using iTextSharp.Net I populate some of the fields with various text. There are some fields which remain empty for editing further down the line.

My question is how can I save the PDF form after populating some of the fields, whilst maintaining the ability to edit the document afterwards.

I've scoured the net and found very little. I'm currently using iTextSharp, although would happily use other existing free/low cost libraries.

iTextSharp does contain a boolean property FormFlattening - however this always seems to be overridden if editing form fields in code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ok after several hours of research I came across an old thread here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5260740/programatically-enable-adobe-pdf-usage-rights/5267583#5267583. It appears that using pdfReader.RemoveUsageRights() allows the PDF to be editable in Adobe Reader.

Answer (score 1):

Ok after several hours of research I came across an old thread here - stackoverflow.com/questions/5260740/…. It appears that using pdfReader.RemoveUsageRights() allows the PDF to be editable in Adobe Reader. (Many thanks to the guys in that thread)